# Is implementing an Annotation a bad idea in Java?

Tags: java, annotations

Currently I have been thinking about the question however, I couldn't find a proper answer. Use case at hand is to create an implementation class for a particular custom annotation so that in the runtime I can simply generate it instead of a POJO.

For instance:

Annotation:

```
@interface CustomAnnotation {
    String date();
}
```

At this stage I need a bean which happens to have the same fields as the annotation. Here I have two options either implement the annotation and create it in runtime or create a class to carry the information.

A)
Implementation of Annotation:

```
public class CustomAnnotationImpl implements CustomAnnotation {

private final String date;

public CustomAnnotationImpl(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}


@Override
public String date() {
    return this.date;
}

@Override
public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
    return CustomAnnotation.class;
}
}
```

B)

```
public class CustomBean {

    private final String date;

    public CustomAnnotationImpl(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return this.date;
    }
}
```

Also keep in my mind that the bean and annotation will be always in sync meaning that bean actually will be always a copy of the annotation.

My question is that what would be the advantages and drawbacks of those, if any? I'm asking this because simply I haven't seen implementation of annotation myself.

Comment: Why does it need to be an annotation exactly?

Comment: It doesn't need to be but I already have the annotation and annotate java classes with it and for other case I need to use more or less the same values as the annotation but I wonder if there is something wrong with the approach at all.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341930/use-cases-for-implementing-annotations#3354409

Comment: @rodolfo how it's a duplicate? I don't wanna know how to do it, I wanna know what's the advantages of it and drawbacks.

Comment: @Ducaz035 advantages and drawbacks compared to what ? a POJO ?

Comment: @rodolfo Is there an disadvantage to use an implemented annotation as a POJO?

Comment: How would you use it could you give an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466184/when-to-use-inheritance just don't. Inheritance is rarely a good idea if you just want to reuse some attributes.

Comment: @rodolfo I just updated the question, please let me know if that's still not understandable.

Comment: @Ducaz035 until java 7 you just need to declare your annotation and use it.

Comment: @Ducaz035 sorry still not clear what do you mean by "... so that in the runtime I can simply generate it instead of a POJO. " what you you want to generate at runtime? the annotation ? and why ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand 100% your question, but it looks like other people already ask something like this.

- [Use cases for implementing annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341930/use-cases-for-implementing-annotations#3354409)
- [Use cases for java annotation and more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515833/use-cases-for-java-annotation-and-more)

Comment: Sorry but they are not related with my question. Please check the answers of those question. I'm more interested in using implemented annotation as POJOs

Comment: I see so you whant to generate the whole pojo at runtime using the annotations?